# How to deploy multiple projects for an MVC website with different property settings files

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, deployment, web-config

I have an MVC website that also references another Class project in my solution called `DAL`

The MVC website has a `settings.settings` file that I am using for my Default database connection string, and this automatically gets updated in my `Web.Config` file.

However my Class project also uses a `settings.settings` file for a database connection (to create a connection if one is not already supplied to it by the MVC project) and I believe this is put into the `App.Config` file, but when it comes to deploying and running this MVC website?

What do I do for the `DAL` project?

I can see it has a `DAL\bin\release\DAL.dll.config` file in that location, does this need to go into the root of the website directory, using the same file path? or should I be doing something else?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to override this setting in your web.config by using the full name. If your project is called DAL you should create a connection string in your web.config which looks something like.

```
<add name="DAL.Properties.Settings.MyDatabaseConnectionString" 
    connectionString="Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=myDatabase;Integrated Security=true"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: Thanks that helped me come up with something, but in my case the DAL project is not referenced in the WebUI at all.